# Animation doesn't happen in first click?

Tags: html, css

the #login div appears visible when a button is clicked, however when the button is clicked the first time after the page reloads, the animation doesnt happen, until I click the button the second time. Everything on the page has the same animation as well and shares those same keyframes as the div.

```
body {

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation:fadein 2s;
    animation:fadein 2s;
    -o-animation:fadein 2s;
}


#login {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px #A4A4A4 solid;
    border-radius:20px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 350px;
    left: 465px;
    bottom: 180px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 1s;
    -moz-animation:fadein 1s;
    animation:fadein 1s;
    -o-animation:fadein 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Include the HTML/JavaScript as well please

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I would use this, it works perfectly:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N3rM9/)**

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="login" class="hide">LOGIN</div>
    <div id="button">BUTTON</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C3C3C3);
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation:fadein 2s;
    animation:fadein 2s;
    -o-animation:fadein 2s;
}


#login {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px #A4A4A4 solid;
    border-radius:20px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 350px;
    left: 465px;
    bottom: 180px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 1s;
    -moz-animation:fadein 1s;
    animation:fadein 1s;
    -o-animation:fadein 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
     $("#login").toggleClass('hide');
});
```